# SPARK SQL GROUPING SETS

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to pass various combination of column sets to my sql query as parameter

eg:

```
Val result=sqlContext.sql(""" select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,count(col6) from table T1 GROUP BY col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 GROUPING SETS ((col1,col2),(col3,col4),(col4, col5)) """)
```

There are several combination for which I need to find the aggregated value.
Is there any way to pass these sets of column as parameter to SQL query instead of hard coding it manually.

Currently I have provided all the combination in sql query but if any new combination comes then again I would need to change the query. I am planning to have all the combination In a file and then read all and pass as parameter to sql query. Is it possible?

Example: Table

```
id category age gender cust_id

1   101 54  M   1111
1   101 54  M   2222
1   101 55  M   3333
1   102 55     F    4444

""" select id, category, age, gender, count(cust_id) from table T1 group By id, category, age, gender
GROUPING SETS ((id,category),(id,age),(id,gender)) """
```

it should produce below result:

```
group by (id, category) - count of cust_id 
1 101 3
1 102 1
group by (id and age) - count of cust_id
1 54 2
1 55 2
group by (id and gender) - count cust_id
1 M 3
1 F 1
```

this is just an example -  I need to pass various different combination to GROPING SETS (not all combination) similarly as parameter in one go OR separately

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you share a small example data and expected output?

Comment: Hi, I have added the example. any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can build SQL dynamically

```
// original slices
var slices = List("(col1, col2)", "(col3, col4)", "(col4, col5)")
// adding new slice
slices = "(col1, col5)" :: slices 
// building SQL dynamically
val q =
s"""
with t1 as
(select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3,
        4 col4, 5 col5, 6 col6)
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,count(col6)
  from t1
group by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
grouping sets ${slices.mkString("(", ",", ")")}
"""
// output
spark.sql(q).show
```

Result

```
scala> spark.sql(q).show
+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|count(col6)|
+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+
|   1|null|null|null|   5|          1|
|   1|   2|null|null|null|          1|
|null|null|   3|   4|null|          1|
|null|null|null|   4|   5|          1|
+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> combination of column sets to my sql query as parameter

`sql` is executed by Spark not source database. It won't reach MySQL at all.

> I have provided all the combination

You don't need `GROUPING SETS` if you want all possible combinations. Just use `CUBE`:

```
SELECT ... FROM table CUBE (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
```

Comment: My sql means - My spark SQL query and I need to do aggregation on various sets of columns not all columns. Earlier I tried CUBE to get all combination but it takes very long time and code fails and also it produces all combination which is not required for my case.